# Rotating Multitouch Gesture in React Native

Tags: react-native, rotation, gesture, multi-touch

Are there any limitations/drawbacks to multitouch gestures, when using React Native?

For example, I want to rotate an item on the screen by holding+dragging two fingers on it in opposing directions:

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check this out [react-native-easy-gestures](https://github.com/keske/react-native-easy-gestures)

```
import Gestures from 'react-native-easy-gestures';

/**
 * Another example:
 * Drag only on x axis;
 * Scale from 0.1 to 7;
 * Do not rotate;
 * On release callback;
 */
<Gestures
  draggable={{
    y: false,
  }}
  scalable={{
    min: 0.1,
    max: 7,
  }}
  rotatable={false}
  onEnd={(event, styles) => {
    console.log(styles);
  }}
>
  <Image
    source={photo}
    style={{
      width,
      height,
    }}
  />
</Gestures>
```